# Should users have/get to confirm a delete?

Tags: website-design, usability

In my database I have a number of types of data, many of which are 'deletable'.

When a user deletes content I store the date of the deletion and purge content that was deleted 30 days ago - This means my support team technically can restore content if users really need it, or eventually we can allow users to restore their own content.

Given this, is it more annoying to confirm with users if they 'really want to delete' content if the content is only 20 minutes of work or so than it's worth? They'd have to at the least ask someone else to restore the data, or worst case would lose it permanently.

It's more of a poll question, or one that could really use some real user data, so if anyone knows if information on this has been collected before, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: it depends.

Imagine for a moment that your application is an invoice builder.

Within the invoice you have multiple line items of goods or services that you will bill to the client. The fine folks at the accounting department build and manage these invoices.

My personal design would involve confirming the deletion of an entire invoice but allow users to freely add/remove individual line items because it has less severe consequences.

You could get around the delete confirmation for entire invoices if you were to provide a "Recently Deleted" tab which clearly states something to the effect of "Deleted invoices will be PERMANENTLY removed from the system after 30 days"

Comment: Another option is to immediately delete (or remove the item from the UI), but give the user an Undo option; Gmail does this, and it's much less annoying that a confirmation.